# update main table based on add or remove Value on another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables.

Stock:

```
ID   Name  Quantity 
1    Table    100 
2    Desk     200
```

and the second table Transfers:

```
ID  Name  AddDate                  AddQT   RemoveDate            RemoveQT Agent 
1   Table  6/19/2015 10:03:06 AM     10                                   alex mortage
2   Table                                   6/19/2015 10:03:06 AM   15    linda raven
```

How can I update the column `Quantity` in the stock table based on the Transfers table columns `AddQT` or `RemoveQT`?

Transfers table is updated via user input (quantity value), 1 record may have an add date so it is a "add quantity" operation. Another record can be registered in SQL to remove quantity by user input.

Comment: From `Table2`, which column?

Comment: To avoid data inconsistency, use triggers!

Comment: hi i said that quantity column in stock must update based on remove qt or add qt

Comment: You could do with adding more information to the question.  Especially around how the Transfer table is updated.  Does it have a single row added at a time, 2 rows or many?  Is the data added to it and then deleted again once the stocks are updated?  You really need to provide more information...

Comment: Also i don't know its a best way to keep track of quantity and add or remove that value with date   I'm in middle of designing this db now..

Comment: Well if you're after db design ideas as well then you should add that to your question and also provide a bit more information around what the requirements are.

Answer (score 0):

An UPDATE statement can do that :

```
UPDATE Stock SET Quantity = sum(isnull(AddQt, 0) - isnull(RemoveQt, 0))
FROM Stock
     LEFT JOIN Transfers on Transfers.Name = Stock.Name
GROUP BY Stock.Name, Transfers.Name
```

If you need it to be automatic, you just have to execute this statement within a trigger on Transfers :

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Transfers_UpdateStock] ON [Transfers] AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
  UPDATE Stock SET Quantity = sum(isnull(AddQt, 0) - isnull(RemoveQt, 0))
  FROM Stock
       LEFT JOIN Transfers on Transfers.Name = Stock.Name
  WHERE Stock.Name in inserted.Name or Stock.Name in deleted.Name
  GROUP BY Stock.Name, Transfers.Name
END
GO
```

Comment: Yeah, but that's not was asked and the stock levels will be wrong if you run it multiple times

Comment: Hi nice update statement Marc so  when user register a add qt or remove qt the quantity  automatically to be updated ?

Comment: to be fair, OP didn't mention anything about automatic update in the first place

Comment: No, it won't be automatic. To be automatic you just need to place this update statement inside an after insert/update/delete trigger on the Transfers Table.

Comment: Yeah, OP needs to provide more info but I read automatic updates from the question title - 'update main table based on add or remove Value on another table'.  Could be wrong though

Comment: no i creating a c# program for that so i can put update statement after a insert query so it can be  automatic process let me test this  UPDATE statement  and see the result Guys Thank you all anyway !

Comment: @dado I have updated the answer to help you creating a trigger that makes it automatic

Comment: trigger is good solution! but update not working because it must check user insert  a add or remove record then join based on that column to update main table

Answer (score 0):

```
Update stock 
set quantity = quantity + 
     (Select sum(coalesce(addqt,0))-(sum(coalesce(removeqt,0))*-1)
      From transfers t
      Where t.id = stock.id)
Where Id in (select id from transfers)
```

/* did this whilst on public transport so can't verify but off top of my head */

/* coalesces around sum are redundant */